# How to speed up the slow query MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Here's my db tables:

```
#1  User

Create Table: CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_superuser` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `is_staff` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_joined` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=133 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


#  settlement
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `settlement` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `short_title` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`),
  UNIQUE KEY `short_title` (`short_title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3553 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8



# sign
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `sign` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `our_side_entity` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(63) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `emails` varchar(1023) NOT NULL,
  `settlement_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sign_our_side_entity_settlement_id_6ccd6800_uniq` (`our_side_entity`,`settlement_id`),
  KEY `sign_settlement_id_07f0b7bb_fk_settlement_id` (`settlement_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sign_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`settlement_id`) REFERENCES `settlement` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3684 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


# sale
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `sale` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `is_leader` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `default_leader_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sale_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `default_leader_id` (`default_leader_id`),
  KEY `sale_id` (`sale_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sale_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`default_leader_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sale_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


# account_token
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `account_token` (
  `token_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `token_type` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=133 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


#   account
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `entity` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_pc` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `settlement_type` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `medium` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `ae_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sale_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sign_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sale_manage_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_new_customer` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `agency` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `related_entity` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `token_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_token_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `account_account_id_medium_b46819c8_uniq` (`account_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `account_ae_id_4d0b721c_fk_auth_user_id` (`ae_id`),
  KEY `account_sale_id_7770cbad_fk_auth_user_id` (`sale_id`),
  KEY `account_sign_id_17d08191_fk_sign_id` (`sign_id`),
  KEY `sale_manage_id` (`sale_manage_id`),
  KEY `account_token` (`account_token_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ae_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`sign_id`) REFERENCES `sign` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_manage_id`) REFERENCES `sale` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`account_token_id`) REFERENCES `account_token` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=119532 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

# sale_leader
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `sale_leader` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `year` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `month` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `leader_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sale_manage_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `leader_id` (`leader_id`),
  KEY `sale_manage_id` (`sale_manage_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sale_leader_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`leader_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sale_leader_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_manage_id`) REFERENCES `sale` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=985 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

#   Table: spend_daily_level
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `spend_daily_level` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `system_value` decimal(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `checked_value` decimal(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sale_leader_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_status` tinyint(3) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `spend_daily_level_date_account_id_f38b1186_uniq` (`date`,`account_id`),
  KEY `spend_daily_level_account_id_f6df4f99_fk_account_id` (`account_id`),
  KEY `sale_leader_id` (`sale_leader_id`),
  KEY `date_active` (`active`,`date`),
  CONSTRAINT `spend_daily_level_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `spend_daily_level_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_leader_id`) REFERENCES `sale_leader` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3682983 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The final query made by ORM is：

```
SELECT `User`.`user_name`, `account`.`medium`, `account`.`type`, `settlement`.`title`, 
`spend_daily_level`.`system_value`, T7.`user_name`, `spend_daily_level`.`date` 
FROM `spend_daily_level` INNER JOIN `account` ON (`spend_daily_level`.`account_id` = `account`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `User` ON (`account`.`sale_id` = `User`.`id`) 
INNER JOIN `sign` ON (`account`.`sign_id` = `sign`.`id`) 
INNER JOIN `settlement` ON (`sign`.`settlement_id` = `settlement`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `sale_leader` ON (`spend_daily_level`.`sale_leader_id` = `sale_leader`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `User` T7 ON (`sale_leader`.`leader_id` = T7.`id`) 
WHERE (`spend_daily_level`.`date` >= '2020-05-13' AND `spend_daily_level`.`date` <= '2020-10-28');
```

Explain SQL ABOVE:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type   | possible_keys                                                                                       | key                                                 | key_len | ref                                          | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | settlement        | index  | PRIMARY                                                                                             | title                                               | 767     | NULL                                         | 3563 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sign              | ref    | PRIMARY,sign_settlement_id_07f0b7bb_fk_settlement_id                                                | sign_settlement_id_07f0b7bb_fk_settlement_id        | 4       | project.settlement.id                    |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | account           | ref    | PRIMARY,account_sign_id_17d08191_fk_sign_id                                                         | account_sign_id_17d08191_fk_sign_id                 | 4       | project.sign.id                          |   28 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | User              | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                             | PRIMARY                                             | 4       | project.account.sale_id                  |    1 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | spend_daily_level | ref    | spend_daily_level_date_account_id_f38b1186_uniq,spend_daily_level_account_id_f6df4f99_fk_account_id | spend_daily_level_account_id_f6df4f99_fk_account_id | 4       | project.account.id                       |   13 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sale_leader       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                             | PRIMARY                                             | 4       | project.spend_daily_level.sale_leader_id |    1 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T7                | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                             | PRIMARY                                             | 4       | project.sale_leader.leader_id            |    1 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

And it cost me about 8s with total 145k rows data. How can I speed up this query?

Great Thanks.

> Updated with adding index suggested

```
#  User  count(110)
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_superuser` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `is_staff` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_joined` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `user_idx` (`id`,`user_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=136 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


# settlement count(4151)
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `settlement` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `short_title` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`),
  UNIQUE KEY `short_title` (`short_title`),
  KEY `settle_idx` (`id`,`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4162 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8



# sign  count(4306)
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `sign` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `our_side_entity` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(63) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `emails` varchar(1023) NOT NULL,
  `settlement_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sign_our_side_entity_settlement_id_6ccd6800_uniq` (`our_side_entity`,`settlement_id`),
  KEY `sign_settlement_id_07f0b7bb_fk_settlement_id` (`settlement_id`),
  KEY `sign_idx` (`id`,`settlement_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sign_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`settlement_id`) REFERENCES `settlement` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4314 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

# sale (46)
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `sale` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `is_leader` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `default_leader_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sale_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `default_leader_id` (`default_leader_id`),
  KEY `sale_id` (`sale_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sale_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`default_leader_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sale_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


# account_token (125)
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `account_token` (
  `token_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `token_type` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=133 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


# account (134663)
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `entity` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_pc` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `settlement_type` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `medium` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `ae_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sale_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sign_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sale_manage_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_new_customer` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `agency` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `related_entity` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_token_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `account_account_id_medium_b46819c8_uniq` (`account_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `account_ae_id_4d0b721c_fk_auth_user_id` (`ae_id`),
  KEY `account_sale_id_7770cbad_fk_auth_user_id` (`sale_id`),
  KEY `account_sign_id_17d08191_fk_sign_id` (`sign_id`),
  KEY `sale_manage_id` (`sale_manage_id`),
  KEY `account_token_id` (`account_token_id`),
  KEY `account_idx` (`id`,`sale_id`,`sign_id`,`medium`,`type`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ae_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`sign_id`) REFERENCES `sign` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_manage_id`) REFERENCES `sale` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`account_token_id`) REFERENCES `account_token` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=134910 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


# sale_leader (1003)
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `sale_leader` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `year` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `month` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `leader_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sale_manage_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `leader_id` (`leader_id`),
  KEY `sale_manage_id` (`sale_manage_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sale_leader_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`leader_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sale_leader_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_manage_id`) REFERENCES `sale` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1007 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

# spend_daily_level (2,177,793)
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `spend_daily_level` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `system_value` decimal(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `checked_value` decimal(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sale_leader_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_status` tinyint(3) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `spend_daily_level_date_account_id_f38b1186_uniq` (`date`,`account_id`),
  KEY `spend_daily_level_account_id_f6df4f99_fk_account_id` (`account_id`),
  KEY `sale_leader_id` (`sale_leader_id`),
  KEY `date_active` (`active`,`date`),
  KEY `spend_idx` (`date`,`account_id`,`system_value`),
  CONSTRAINT `spend_daily_level_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `spend_daily_level_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_leader_id`) REFERENCES `sale_leader` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4181988 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8



EXPLAIN SELECT `User`.`user_name`, `account`.`medium`, `account`.`type`, `settlement`.`title`, `spend_daily_level`.`system_value`, T7.`user_name`, `spend_daily_level`.`date` FROM `spend_daily_level` INNER JOIN `account` ON (`spend_daily_level`.`account_id` = `account`.`id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `User` ON (`account`.`sale_id` = `User`.`id`) INNER JOIN `sign` ON (`account`.`sign_id` = `sign`.`id`) INNER JOIN `settlement` ON (`sign`.`settlement_id` = `settlement`.`id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `sale_leader` ON (`spend_daily_level`.`sale_leader_id` = `sale_leader`.`id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `User` T7 ON (`sale_leader`.`leader_id` = T7.`id`) WHERE (`spend_daily_level`.`date` >= '2020-05-13' AND `spend_daily_level`.`date` <= '2020-10-28');
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                 | key                                                 | key_len | ref                                          | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | settlement        | index  | PRIMARY,settle_idx                                                                                            | title                                               | 767     | NULL                                         | 4214 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sign              | ref    | PRIMARY,sign_settlement_id_07f0b7bb_fk_settlement_id,sign_idx                                                 | sign_settlement_id_07f0b7bb_fk_settlement_id        | 4       | bv_crm_1029.settlement.id                    |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | account           | ref    | PRIMARY,account_sign_id_17d08191_fk_sign_id,account_idx                                                       | account_sign_id_17d08191_fk_sign_id                 | 4       | bv_crm_1029.sign.id                          |   20 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | User              | eq_ref | PRIMARY,user_idx                                                                                              | PRIMARY                                             | 4       | bv_crm_1029.account.sale_id                  |    1 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | spend_daily_level | ref    | spend_daily_level_date_account_id_f38b1186_uniq,spend_daily_level_account_id_f6df4f99_fk_account_id,spend_idx | spend_daily_level_account_id_f6df4f99_fk_account_id | 4       | bv_crm_1029.account.id                       |   20 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sale_leader       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                       | PRIMARY                                             | 4       | bv_crm_1029.spend_daily_level.sale_leader_id |    1 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T7                | eq_ref | PRIMARY,user_idx                                                                                              | PRIMARY                                             | 4       | bv_crm_1029.sale_leader.leader_id            |    1 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

It seems that the index added not used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try adding the following indices:

```sql
CREATE INDEX spend_idx ON spend_daily_level (date, account_id, system_value);
CREATE INDEX account_idx ON account (id, sale_id, sign_id, medium, type);
CREATE INDEX user_idx ON User (id, user_name);
CREATE INDEX sign_idx ON sign (id, settlement_id);
CREATE INDEX settle_idx ON settlement (id, title);
```

These first index `spend_idx` covers the entire `WHERE` clause.  It, along with the other indices, cover the joins and the select clause.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it seems query cost same time after I add `index` as your suggestion

Comment: Please let me know what your `EXPLAIN` plan says.  Are _any_ of the indices I suggested being used?

Comment: As an aside , I find it surprising that a sale id references a user id

Comment: @Strawberry You just gave me the weirdest deja vu.  Yes, I also find it odd, and the second join to the user table looks fishy to me.  Maybe this is why the indices aren't being used, or maybe there isn't even enough data to make it worthwhile to use an index.

Comment: I've updated above, and it seems that indices not being used

Comment: How much data is in each of the tables?  Note that for tables with just a few hundred rows, MySQL might not even mess around and use the index, because scanning is already performant enough.

Comment: I've updated the data count. And the amount of base table `User`  is `100+` and `sale` is `40+`

Comment: Well some of your tables are very small.  This could at least partly explain why my answer isn't working for you (and if MySQL decides not to use an index, then you're basically stuck).

Comment: Thanks, in this case, how can I do some optimizing work?

Comment: I've tried to add more than 1k data in each table but query speed is still slow